# Bootstrap layout - Should we always use XS col class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I was reading about bootstrap 12 grid column layout.

The author used `.col-sm-8` class & said on `small, medium & large` devices the DOM element will take 8 column space but on `XS` device the DOM element will take whole width See the below image

In another example he used `.col-xs-4` class and said this will take width of 4 columns on `XS, SM, M & LG` devices.

**Does this means we should always use `xs*` classes irrespective of the device as it will automatically adjust on bigger devices ?**

What are the pros/cons of always using `xs` class?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap is built with mobile-first designs in mind, which is why XS columns would be the default choice. In this row:

```
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
```

We'll have 3 equal-width columns on any screen size. Larger breakpoints are irrelevant, because we're already at the default layout.

However, in this row:

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

You'll see that there are 3 columns on medium/large screens and 1 column (stacked) in small and xsmall screens.

If you want it to "break" at different screen sizes, you use sm, m, and l columns. If you never need it to "break," using xs all the time is fine.

Comment: I understand how a particular style will work on larger or smaller device That part is clear. What you are suggesting here is using `xs` style will work fine in all the cases.

Comment: @SharpCoder Yes and no. If you didn't want a responsive layout (design it out on mobile and it never changes), then you can do all XS and it's fine. But that kind of eliminates the point of using Bootstrap. If you want it to look different on different size screens, you'll end up using a mix of the different size columns.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use only one class if your are try to target different devices, for example let's say that you have a galley and you want to show 4 pics on desktop devices 2 on table and only one on phone devices.

Below a example to give you an idea.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <figure class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img .../>
    </figure>
    <figure class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img .../>
    </figure>
    <figure class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img .../>
    </figure>
    <figure class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img .../>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would show 3 pics on desktops I think.